# How to store an encoded variable for each owner of an NFT that only they can decode?

Tags: encoding, hash, cryptography, blockchain, solidity

Let's say for example we want to store a URL on chain for that specific NFT but we do not want anyone else to be able to see the URL.

We can have a function in the contract that asks for an ID and firstly can only be called by the owner of that particilar NFT ID but will secondly be able to decode the URL we stored for it.

Comment: The "cryptography" tag would seem to be the whole answer, and the "blockchain" tag feels irrelevant. If it is the owner who writes it, use symmetric encryption, and only they can decode the data. If it is others who write it, use asymmetric encryption, and again, only the owner of the private key can decode the data. How does putting this in a smart contract change anything? Perhaps you can expand this question to explain the special case at hand. (In any of these cases, it's going to be off-topic for SO, but at least understanding why there's a question may help point you to the right site.)

Comment: (This would become a SO question if it applied to specific implementations in specific languages. It would be a crypto.stackexchange.com question if it were tied to cryptography, though most smart contract work has only tangental connection to cryptography. As a general question, security.stackexchange.com may be appropriate, but you'd need to explain why this isn't just "use standard encryption.")

Comment: Thanks Rob, I updated the question/content with hopefully more details.